# Can Python setuptools install files outside dist-packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

Is it *actually* possible to install data files from a *sdist* to arbitrary locations outside the `sys.prefix` directory using setuptools?

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-additional-files) implies that it is possible to do so, using an absolute path in the `data_files` *directory* part, but in practice the leading slash seems to be ignored.

For instance with `data_files=[('/opt/foo/bar', [...])]`, the files should be installed into the directory */opt/foo/bar*.  But they all end up in */usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/opt/foo/bar*, which is no use to man nor beast.

I suspect that it used to work - has it been changed/broken recently?

(Using pip 8.1.1, Python 3.4, setuptools 20.9.0)

Answer (score 1):

Best bet would be to override `install` with your own [cmdclass](https://docs.python.org/3.4/distutils/extending.html) and move the files yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it's all pip's fault.  Given a *sdist*, pip helpfully creates a *wheel* before installing that. But wheels [can't install files outside *dist-packages*](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/wheel/issues/92).

Luckily you can knock some sense into pip by chucking an error, causing it to fall back to installing the *sdist* you wanted in the first place.

```
# in setup.py
if 'bdist_wheel' in sys.argv:
    raise RuntimeError("This setup.py does not support wheels")
```

(Thanks to Benjamin Bach)